# Expressing properties of graded algebras in terms of the $\mathbb{G}_m$action

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory

Let us fix a base ring $k$. The category of $\mathbb{Z}$-graded $k$-algebras is equivalent to the category of $\mathbb{G}_m$ equivariant affine $k$-schemes. The following 2 properties often come up when constructing the $Proj$ of a graded ring: Let $A$ be a graded $k$-algebra.

1. The zeroth graded piece is the base ring $A_0 =k$
2. The algebra $A_\bullet$ is positively graded. i.e. $A_j=0$ for all $j<0$.
3. The canonical multiplication homomorphism $Sym^\bullet A_1 \to A_\bullet$ is surjective.

I'm trying to find equivalent characterization of the above properties which don't use the aforementioned equivalence. In other words I want the above 3 properties expressed in terms of properties of $\mathbb{G}_m$-equivariant schemes (orbits, stabilizers, fixed points etc.).

Comment: For example $A_0$ is the ring of $\mathbb{G}_m$-invariant functions, so $A_0=k$ iff all the $\mathbb{G}_m$-invariant functions are constant

Comment: The grading is non-negative if and only if the action of $\mathbb{G}_m$ extends to an action of the monoid $\mathbb{G}_m\cup\{0\}$.

Comment: Great! So only 3. left...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $V$ be an affine variety with a $\mathbb{G}_m$-action. Then you should think of $A_0$ as a good model for $V/\mathbb{G}_m$. So being connected says something like $\mathbb{G}_m$ acts transitively- at least from the point of view of functions. Being positively graded is saying something like the action of $\mathbb{G}_m$ extending to an action of the monoid scheme $\mathbb{A}^1$ (under multiplication). The last condition is more involved: The module $A_1$ is the set of $\mathbb{G}_m$-equivariant functions to $\mathbb{A}^1$ where we use the scaling action on $\mathbb{A}^1$. (So it's kind of like "linear" functions on $V$). This is a vector space over $k$, call its *dual* $W$ and view it as a variety. There's a natural equivariant map $V \to W$ given by evaluation (that's why we took the dual of the vector space of functions). We're asking that this equivariant map be an embedding. So, while $V$ is not a vector space with the standard linear action of $\mathbb{G}_m$, it can be embedded in one in some natural way.

Comment: looks like some people in the comments beat me to numbers 1 and 2

Comment: I should mention that another justification for viewing $A_0$ as a model for $V/\mathbb{G}_m$ is that $A_0$ is precisely the primitives for the coaction of the Hopf algebra representing $\mathbb{G}_m$; and more generally the primitives of a Hopf algebra action are like a model for geometrically taking the quotient in a well-behaved way.

Comment: This is so simple! So basically the conditions together mean that $V$ has a "transitive" action of $\mathbb{A}^1$ s.t. the natural map to the vector space dual to linear functions is an embedding. Thank you!

Comment: One has to be cautious about picturing the action as transitive. The condition isn't that $V/\mathbb{G}_m$ is a point, just that this quotient doesn't have any non-constant global functions. For instance, $V$ can have arbitrarily high dimension, so the action might be very far from transitive.

Comment: @JulianRosen Could it be interpreted as being transitive after we throw away all the finite orbits?

Comment: Consider $V=\mathbb{A}^n$ with the standard action. The action is very far from transitive, and most of the orbits are infinite, but the invariant are still just the constants.

Comment: @JulianRosen Oh I see. What about "no orbit is a divisor"?

Comment: Assuming the grading is non-negative, the action extends to the monoid $\mathbb{A}^1$. The action of $0\in\mathbb{A}^1$ on $A$ is projection onto $A_0$, so $A_0=k$ iff the action of $0\in\mathbb{A}^1$ on $V$ maps everything to a point.

Comment: For example it could mean that $V/\mathbb{G}_m$ is proper (take $V$ to be the punctured cone on a projective variety)

Comment: Julian- this is why I said "from the point of view of functions" but you're absolutely right that saying transitive is probably too misleading.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Dylan Wilson's answer, condition (2) is indeed just a continuation of $\mathbb{G}_m$-action to an $\mathbb{A}^1$-action, since $\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{A}^1) \hookrightarrow \mathcal{O}(\mathbb{G}_m): \mathbb{k}[t] \hookrightarrow \mathbb{k}[t, t^{-1}]$. Condition (1) is trickier, since the action of $\mathbb{G}_m$ on $V$ will have inseparable orbits --- see the action on $\mathbb{A}^n$. Thus we can't think of it as transitivity (not of the group action at least, the monoid $\mathbb{A}^1$ action is transitive in a sense that any two points can be mapped to a same point). Instead we should look at it together with condition (2), which implies that the action of $\mathbb{G}_m$ has fixed points: for any $x \in V$ the point $0\cdot x \in V$ will be fixed. Here $0 \in \mathbb{A}^1$ and its action exists by (2). Condition (1) then reduces to the statement that the $\mathbb{G}_m$-action has a *unique* fixed point. On the level of functions it is given by a graded morphism $\mathcal{O}(V) \to \mathbb k$ as graded algebras. Condition (3) means that the action is *free* if we remove that single fixed point. We can see it because the action on $A_1^*$ is a free action apart from $0 \in A_1^*$ and the embedding $V \hookrightarrow A_1^*$ is $\mathbb{G}_m$-equivariant, as a morphism of graded algebras.

The simplest example where you can see all those statements is the obvious action on $\mathbb{A}^n$. On the other hand, consider the obvious action of $\mathbb{G}_m$ on itself. It corresponds to the natural grading on $\mathbb{k}[t,t^{-1}]$. The reasons (2) fails here is obvious. Since there is no morphism $\mathbb{k}[t,t^{-1}] \to \mathbb{k}$, the action has no fixed points. In this case (1) indeed reduces to transitivity. Instead of (3) we have that $Sym(A_1 \oplus A_{-1}) \to A_\bullet$ is surjective. This also implies that the action is free, for the same reasons as above.